# Page stuck on logoout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

The problem occurs once the logout button is pressed, or when I add this code:

```
 this.local = new Storage();
     this.local.get('token').then((value)=>{
         this.token=value;
 });
```

The page is stuck and the chrome browser needs to be restarted. What I'm trying to do is get the token variable from storage when logout is pressed to remove that token.

**The page:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import {Admin} from "../pages/admin/admin";
import {Page1} from "../pages/page1/page1";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html',
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = Page1;
  token:any;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
  public local : Storage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,public storage:Storage) {
      this.initializeApp();
      this.local = new Storage();
      this.local.get('token').then((value)=>{
          this.token=value;
      });
      // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
      this.pages = [
          { title: 'Page one', component: Page1 },
          { title: 'Page Two', component: Page2 },
          { title: 'Admin', component: Admin }
      ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
      });
  }

  openPage(page) {
      // Reset the content nav to have just this page
      // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
      this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  Logout() {
      console.log("logout check");
      this.local.remove('username');
      this.local.remove('token');
      this.nav.setRoot(Page1);
      this.token="";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and its not stuck anymore..
I removed all local (Storage variables) then i defined storage: Storage in my constructor and i use it as ionic 2 change log explain as storage.get(key).